# Where does the function onLoad() in my Seaside generated html document come from, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

Some (not all) of the html documents generated by Seaside have these elements in it:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">

<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/function onLoad(){};/*]]>*/</script>
```

I do not use any Javascript in these documents and i wonder, where this comes from, and if/how i can prevent these parts from being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaside generates this markup in the class `WADefaultScriptGenerator`. Unfortunately the markup needs to be generated even if you don't use Javascript, as this is not know when Seaside opens the `<body>` tag.

You can customize (or avoid the Javascript markup generation) by subclassing `WAScriptGenerator` and setting your custom class in the application configuration. Either through the configuration interface or programmatically:

```
application := WAAdmin register: MyRootComponent asApplicationAt: 'myapp'.
application preferenceAt: #scriptGeneratorClass put: MyScriptGenerator.
```